# How can I download hard copies of the drivers installed by Windows Update?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-update

I have a laptop running Windows 10 on which I recently used Windows Update to install several drivers. However, I want to have hard copies of my drivers on hand in case I ever need to reinstall them offline, and these particular drivers are not available on the laptop manufacturer's website.

Is there a way I can download a hard copy of the exact drivers that were installed by Windows Update?

My first thought was to use the Microsoft Update Catalog because it probably does have these drivers on it somewhere. But searching that site isn't particularly fruitful because there doesn't seem be a way to search for something very specific. Unlike with updates, these drivers do not have a unique ID number I can use, and it always returns several different versions of the same driver. I don't know how to be sure which one -- if any of them -- is the right one. Is there a way to specifically get the one installed by Windows Update on my system?

Edit: To anyone reading this question, I have posted an answer of how to get at hard copies of the drivers *without* using the Microsoft Update catalog here: [How can I obtain hard copies of drivers installed by Windows Update without using the Microsoft Update Catalog?](https://superuser.com/questions/1769404/how-can-i-obtain-hard-copies-of-drivers-installed-by-windows-update-without-usin)

Answer (score 1):

There are over 16 Million combinations of drivers and computers in that catalog (source: Microsoft seminar) and so the catalog may not work for (and I can see why not). You will need the specific card / part details to get the correct driver.

So then use the computer manufacturer's driver update site or the make of the card (peripheral) site to get these drivers.

I do this with Lenovo machines but the method will work for Dell and HP. After that, you are at the mercy of the card / part manufacturers.

Otherwise do as most people do and just let Windows do the work and find the correct driver