# How can I obtain hard copies of drivers installed by Windows Update without using the Microsoft Update Catalog?

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-update

I have a system where I need to obtain hard copies of the drivers installed by Windows Update. However, I don't want to use the Microsoft Update Catalog as it's very difficult, if not downright impossible, to find the exact drive Windows Update installed from it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download hard copies of the drivers installed by Windows Update?](https://superuser.com/questions/1768348/how-can-i-download-hard-copies-of-the-drivers-installed-by-windows-update)

Comment: @John No, the question is specifically how to do this *without* using the Microsoft Update catalog. It took me days of work to figure out how to do this, and I'm keen to share my knowledge with others so that they don't have to go through the same hassle. Hence me answering my own question.

Comment: @music2myear No, again this is asking how to do it without using the Microsoft update catalog. That answer is once again using the update catalog.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In Windows 10 and later, to get hard copies of the drivers, after running Windows update, execute the following command in a terminal window with Administrator privileges:

```
pnputil /export-driver * C:\path\to\driver-archive
```

This will export all of the drivers installed on the system, including those installed by Windows update, in a form that makes them easy to install again without an internet connection or by using Windows Update directly.

To determine which driver goes with which device, you can open the inf file for the driver and scroll down to where the names of the products or hardware are, usually at the bottom of the file.